# Calculating distance to minimum of similar cases (observations) in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that describes the results of applying 3 algorithms to a number of *cases*.For each combination of *algorithm* and *case*, there is a *result*.

```
df = data.frame(
  c("case1", "case1", "case1", "case2", "case2", "case2"),
  c("algo1", "algo2", "algo3", "algo1", "algo2", "algo3"),
  c(10, 11, 12, 22, 23, 20)
  );
names(df) <- c("case", "algorithm", "result");
df
```

These algorithms **aim to minimize the *result* value**. So for each algorithm and case I want to **calculate the gap to the lowest achieved result**, achieved by any algorithm for that same case.

```
gap <- function(caseId, result) {
  filtered = subset(df, case==caseId)
  return (result - min(filtered[,'result']));
}
```

When I apply that function manually, I get the expected results.

```
gap("case1", 10)  # prints 0, since 10 is the best value for case1
gap("case1", 11)  # prints 1, since 11-10=1
gap("case1", 12)  # prints 2, since 12-10=1

gap("case2", 22)  # prints 2, since 22-20=2
gap("case2", 23)  # prints 3, since 23-20=3
gap("case2", 20)  # prints 0, since 20 is the best value for case2
```

However, when I want to calculate a new column across the whole dataset, I get bogus results for case2.

```
df$gap <- gap(df$case, df$result)
df
```

This produces

```
   case algorithm result gap
1 case1     algo1     10   0
2 case1     algo2     11   1
3 case1     algo3     12   2
4 case2     algo1     22  12
5 case2     algo2     23  13
6 case2     algo3     20  10
```

It seems that now the gap function is working against the overall *result* minimum of the whole dataframe, whereas it should just consider rows with the same *case*. Maybe the subset filtering in the gap function is not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(case) %>% 
  mutate(result = result - min(result))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   case [2]
#    case algorithm result
#   <fctr>    <fctr>  <dbl>
#1  case1     algo1      0
#2  case1     algo2      1
#3  case1     algo3      2
#4  case2     algo1      2
#5  case2     algo2      3
#6  case2     algo3      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ave` to obtain minimum value for each group and subtract from `result`

```
df$result - ave(df$result, df$case, FUN = min)
#[1] 0 1 2 2 3 0
```

Comment: This one also works. To add a column "gap" which I wanted, one needs to use `df$gap <- df$result - ave(df$result, df$case, FUN = min)`.